# Why is my regex statement performing poorly in comparison to separate statements?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Running this regexpr can cause a timeout on a *small 500 line document*. It takes a very long time to computer if it does work.

```
^(\s+)([if|foreach|else].*?\)) ([a-z]|\$)
```

Instead, running the following 3 regexprs separately and in succession.

```
^(\s+)(if.*?\)) ([a-z]|\$)
^(\s+)(else.*?\)) ([a-z]|\$)
^(\s+)(foreach.*?\)) ([a-z]|\$)
```

Runs a heck of a lot faster than the first.

**Why?**

I've tested this with Sublime-Text-3 reg expression. And I've tested it on www.regexr.com.

Comment: `^(\s+)((?:if|foreach|else).*?\)) ([a-z]|\$)`

Comment: The patterns aren't really equivalent. `[...]` represents a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so it's matching any one character of `i, f, |, o, r, e, a, c`, etc. rather than using the pipe for [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Oh, I see that I misunderstood the use of classes. Well, this question was answered in the comments. Do you think this question could be restated and still be valuable, or would it be better to delete the question? Suggestions on proceeding tactfully?